# In Cognos framework manager how to use excel file as my data source

Tags: frameworks, cognos, cognos-bi

I need to create new data source connection which points to an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to use Excel files as data source in Cognos Business Intelligence:

Through ODBC datasource in Framework Manager (ODBC is limited to Compatible Query Mode)
You can connect to a Microsoft Excel data source by using Excel ODBC drive using the following steps:

1. Create a system DSN in the Windows ODBC Administrator. The excel
   file should be in a common  location for Framework Manager and the
   Cognos Server.
2. Create a new data source in Cognos Connection, select ODBC (Windows
   only) option.
3. Enter the system DSN name you created in Step 1 under ODBC data
   source property.

By using the External Data functionality.

By using My Data Sets (available in Cognos 10.2.2)

The information above can also be located at the following link:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21338951

Comment: Though I tried all possible things I am getting error.  UDA-SQL-0043 The underlying database detected an error during processing the SQL request.[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'

Comment: I referred below link
http://www.cognossource.com/excel-odbc-data-advisor/

Comment: When do you get the above error?  On import into FM, on testing a query subject?

Comment: In FM it works, I am able to validate data and see some data. While building the report in report studio and doing view tabular data I get above error. So it is some thing to do with data source only I believe I mean way the DS is created.

Comment: In theory if FM and CA are on the same server they should be using the same ODBC connection and data source.  Can you try doing a like comparison between what you are testing in FM and CA.  Meaning if you test a table in FM can you test the tabular for that table only in CA.